# Time for a Box Upgrade (to 200A)?

Tags: electrical

So I have 2 units on my property with solar on each, totaling 7K. My front unit I use as an office and already upgraded the box there to 200A. In the back I still have 100. I have central air right now, but that's about it, the rest is lights. I realized in the office unit the only thing that was still gas was the stove so last year I got an induction stove and turned off the account (saving around $300/year). My back house I will eventually go completely off gas but I have a Takagi tankless right now. When that dies will replace with electric. Then I have a gas stove and a gas furnace for my AC. And a gas dryer.

Few weeks ago I had finally had enough of it sounding like a helicopter battle was occurring under the house when the washing machine was completing its cycle. Got a new machine (which incidentally has an annual use of $10 of energy).

When the dryer dies I will for sure replace it with an electric one.

Last variable: I am in LA where DWP instituted a program to switch to Time of Use meters. I did that over a year ago and my meter has run backwards in the A and B periods a lot, so anything I move to electric is running for free.

Question is should I just do the box now? or try and hang the dryer and see if I can get away with it.

Comment: I love to hear your idea to switch to electric power when the president has made it policy to increase rates. Your solar will make your meter run backwards in the daylight for up to ~20 years then you have pay for a new set of solar panels, and how many inverters will die in this time line. I have installed, done the math it just doesn't add up from the total cost and repairs I have done, but it is a small area that makes me lots as not very many Sparkys have degrees in electronics.

Comment: If I am making more than I am using, how does rising rates affect me? I hope they do raise the rates, a lot. That's what's making solar spread. I didn't do it to save money, but 2015 was the best year for solar ever, and mostly in places where the rates were highest. I have no idea what you are talking about: you are saying the numbers aren't there but rates are going way up? I am not worried about inverter failures. Frankly I want to install more solar. There's a bill they are trying to pass in CA making it so the utility has to pay you for excess energy. Good luck.

Comment: Rob I am saying even with selling excess back the initial cost, maintenance and repair and replacement it did not pay back in my area. You live in a warmer area so your peak production will be higher but this also shortens the life of the system .

Comment: @EdBeal hate to hear that. Well only time will tell. I have had zero maintenance on my system so far and am in year 7. I think without the credits I was due to be even in year 11. As for the panels being dead in 20 they are warranted for 25. I read that they are likely to make it 40. If I even came out even I would consider it a huge win. That much less coal that was burned to make my living room a tad cooler.

Comment: Sounds like a great setup Rob. If you go to a 200 amp panel in each unit you could back feed up to 40 amps on each panel. Adding to your solar setup is easy now with micro inverters. The APS inverters I just bought have a 25 year warranty. Most line inverters are 10 to 12. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know for sure if an upgrade is required, is to do a load calculation on the building.  For this you'll need to know the electrical requirements of all the major electrical equipment (A/C, Heat, hot water, range, dryer, etc), and the square footage of the building.

In my opinion, any home that's all electric, should probably have at least 200 amp service. Obviously this is a generalization, based on the average home in my area.

Comment: I agree with the 200 amp service. 3va per square foot is the calculation for lighting and general outlets, 3 20 amp circuits (1500va) 2 for the kitchen and 1 for the laundry these loads are considered continuous and require 125% of the value. Then add: range, cook top, water , heater, dryer (5kw or name plate need to use the largest on the dryer). The larger of heating or air conditioning, that do not run at the same time. If a heat pump 100% of the AC side and 65% of the supplemental electric heat. Other appliances dishwasher, garbage disposal, fans, compactor. this will give a base value.